# Javascript - Como fazer para agregar a todos os href="" de uma div um domínio "http://site.com"

Tags: javascript

> Estou com um sisteminha que busca sugestões de produtos via ajax. Ele puxa as informações, porém essas informações vem de um site externo, e ele tá com a URL local. `href="/produto/123`, preciso fazer com que seja inserido em todos os `href=""`, o domínio do site. Ex: `href="http:/meusite.com/produto/123`. **Pra uma explicação melhor, preciso que todos os `href=""` contidos dentro de:**

```
<div class="recommendation-shelf"></div>
```

Seja agregado `http://meusite.com` dentro de `href="<urldomeusite>/produto/123"` ficando assim:

> href="http://meusite.com/produto/123"

Obs: Se possível, em Javascript Puro...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe uma maneira nova para fazer isso. Foi adicionado ao HTML 5 e é o [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base).

O `base` diz ao browser que todos os urls que não são absolutos começam nesse url. Só podes ter 1 por página, os outros serão ignorados.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```html
<base href="http://pt.stackoverflow.com">
<a href="/questions/tagged/javascript+html">Tag JavaScript</a>
```

Se há sites diferentes e precisas de mudar somente em alguns elementos podes fazer assim:

```js
var site = 'http://meusite.com';
var ancoras = document.querySelectorAll('.recommendation-shelf a');
[].forEach.call(ancoras, function(a) {
    var href = a.getAttribute('href').split('/').filter(Boolean);
    a.href = [site].concat(href).join('/');
    
    // isto é só para o exemplo
    a.innerHTML = a.href;
});
```

```css
a {display: block;}
```

```html
<a href="/questions/tagged/javascript+html">Tag JavaScript</a>
<div class="recommendation-shelf">
    <a href="questions/tagged/javascript">Tag JavaScript</a>
    <a href="/questions/tagged/html">Tag HTML</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estou usando jquery

#### #Editei

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".recommendation-shelf").change(function() {
    $('.recommendation-shelf').find('a').each(function(i, obj) {
        var href = $(obj).attr('href');
        $(obj).attr('href', 'http://meusite.com/'+href)
    });
  })
})
```

Comment: Quero algo simples, que utilize Javascript Puro.

Comment: Posso te garantir que o jeito mais simples é usar JQuery do que javascript puro.  Tinha um erro no meu script e já atualizei

Comment: @BrenoPerucchi respeito sua opinião mas discordo profundamente que o jeito mais simples é usar jQuery, ou seja, é um direito seu ter sua opinião, mas é só um opinião. Só quero deixar claro para quem lê aqui não achar que isso é uma verdade absoluta.

Comment: @bigown para a minha realidade é sim mais complicado javascript puro do que jquery. Entendo a diferença de opinião, mas cada um tem a sua. Não quero polemizar porque entendo, realmente, o que você quis dizer. Efetuarei uma mudança no comentário se pudesse.